# Rvestを用いた複数のページからのtableデータの取り出し

Tags: r, database, web-scraping

Rでwebページからサッカーのtableデータを取り出し、csvファイルに出力したいと考えています。
一日だけのデータならば、以下のコードで成功しました。

```
html <- read_html()
data <-html %>%
html_table(fill=TRUE)
```

しかし、一ヶ月分のデータを得るために以下のコード

```
for (i in 1:31)
```

を用いた場合、一ヶ月分ではなく、31日のデータだけ取り出されました。
一ヶ月分のデータを取り出すためにはどのようなコードが必要ですか？
追記：はじめに

```
result<- NULL
```

とし、最後に

```
result<-　bind_rows(result,data)
```

で書き出して見ると、は31日のデータが31回結合されていました。

Comment: データを見ないとコメントが難しいのですが、reprex (再現可能な例)は提示できますか？ 実際のデータじゃなくて良いので、同形状のデータを定義出来るコードを https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex などを使って貼り付けてみてください

Answer (score 0):

日付の扱いは Tidyverse パッケージ群の一つ lubridate を使うと超絶ラクになります。

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, lubridate)

> lubridate::days_in_month(as_date("2021-1-1"))
Jan 
 31
```

大量データ処理に便利な関数が山盛りですので、ぜひ慣れて見てください。

```
> p_funs(lubridate)
  [1] ".__C__Duration"                   ".__C__Interval"                   ".__C__Period"                     ".__C__Timespan"                  
  [5] ".__T__-:base"                     ".__T__[:base"                     ".__T__[[:base"                    ".__T__[[<-:base"                 
  [9] ".__T__[<-:base"                   ".__T__*:base"                     ".__T__/:base"                     ".__T__%/%:base"                  
 [13] ".__T__%%:base"                    ".__T__%m-%:lubridate"             ".__T__%m+%:lubridate"             ".__T__%within%:lubridate"        
 [17] ".__T__+:base"                     ".__T__$:base"                     ".__T__$<-:base"                   ".__T__Arith:base"                
 [21] ".__T__as_date:lubridate"          ".__T__as_datetime:lubridate"      ".__T__as.character:base"          ".__T__as.difftime:base"          
 [25] ".__T__as.duration:lubridate"      ".__T__as.interval:lubridate"      ".__T__as.numeric:base"            ".__T__as.period:lubridate"       
 [29] ".__T__c:base"                     ".__T__Compare:methods"            ".__T__date<-:lubridate"           ".__T__day<-:lubridate"           
 [33] ".__T__format_ISO8601:lubridate"   ".__T__hour<-:lubridate"           ".__T__minute<-:lubridate"         ".__T__month<-:lubridate"         
 [37] ".__T__qday<-:lubridate"           ".__T__reclass_timespan:lubridate" ".__T__rep:base"                   ".__T__second<-:lubridate"        
 [41] ".__T__show:methods"               ".__T__time_length:lubridate"      ".__T__year<-:lubridate"           "%--%"                            
 [45] "%m-%"                             "%m+%"                             "%within%"                         "add_with_rollback"               
 [49] "am"                               "Arith"                            "as_date"                          "as_datetime"                     
 [53] "as.difftime"                      "as.duration"                      "as.interval"                      "as.period"                       
 [57] "ceiling_date"                     "Compare"                          "cyclic_encoding"                  "date"                            
 [61] "Date"                             "date_decimal"                     "date<-"                           "day"                             
 [65] "day<-"                            "days"                             "days_in_month"                    "ddays"                           
 [69] "decimal_date"                     "dhours"                           "dmicroseconds"                    "dmilliseconds"                   
 [73] "dminutes"                         "dmonths"                          "dmy"                              "dmy_h"                           
 [77] "dmy_hm"                           "dmy_hms"                          "dnanoseconds"                     "dpicoseconds"                    
 [81] "dseconds"                         "dst"                              "duration"                         "dweeks"                          
 [85] "dyears"                           "dym"                              "epiweek"                          "epiyear"                         
 [89] "fast_strptime"                    "fit_to_timeline"                  "floor_date"                       "force_tz"                        
 [93] "force_tzs"                        "format_ISO8601"                   "guess_formats"                    "hm"                              
 [97] "hms"                              "hour"                             "hour<-"                           "hours"                           
[101] "int_aligns"                       "int_diff"                         "int_end"                          "int_end<-"                       
[105] "int_flip"                         "int_length"                       "int_overlaps"                     "int_shift"                       
[109] "int_standardize"                  "int_start"                        "int_start<-"                      "intersect"                       
[113] "interval"                         "is.Date"                          "is.difftime"                      "is.duration"                     
[117] "is.instant"                       "is.interval"                      "is.period"                        "is.POSIXct"                      
[121] "is.POSIXlt"                       "is.POSIXt"                        "is.timepoint"                     "is.timespan"                     
[125] "isoweek"                          "isoyear"                          "leap_year"                        "local_time"                      
[129] "make_date"                        "make_datetime"                    "make_difftime"                    "mday"                            
[133] "mday<-"                           "mdy"                              "mdy_h"                            "mdy_hm"                          
[137] "mdy_hms"                          "microseconds"                     "milliseconds"                     "minute"                          
[141] "minute<-"                         "minutes"                          "month"                            "month<-"                         
[145] "ms"                               "my"                               "myd"                              "NA_Date_"                        
[149] "NA_POSIXct_"                      "nanoseconds"                      "now"                              "origin"                          
[153] "parse_date_time"                  "parse_date_time2"                 "period"                           "period_to_seconds"               
[157] "picoseconds"                      "pm"                               "POSIXct"                          "pretty_dates"                    
[161] "qday"                             "qday<-"                           "quarter"                          "reclass_date"                    
[165] "reclass_timespan"                 "rollback"                         "rollbackward"                     "rollforward"                     
[169] "round_date"                       "second"                           "second<-"                         "seconds"                         
[173] "seconds_to_period"                "semester"                         "setdiff"                          "show"                            
[177] "stamp"                            "stamp_date"                       "stamp_time"                       "time_length"                     
[181] "today"                            "tz"                               "tz<-"                             "union"                           
[185] "wday"                             "wday<-"                           "week"                             "week<-"                          
[189] "weeks"                            "with_tz"                          "yday"                             "yday<-"                          
[193] "ydm"                              "ydm_h"                            "ydm_hm"                           "ydm_hms"                         
[197] "year"                             "year<-"                           "years"                            "ym"                              
[201] "ymd"                              "ymd_h"                            "ymd_hm"                           "ymd_hms"                         
[205] "yq"
```